# Windows store app pinch zoom handling

Tags: windows

I have followed the instruction on msdn about [GestureRecognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR241937)! for handling pinch guesture.  However, I can't get the `ManipulationUpdated` called.  Is there anything I'm missing?

In my `C#` class,

```
    `private GestureRecognizer gesture = new GestureRecognizer();`
```

In my constructor:

```
    gesture.GestureSettings = GestureSettings.ManipulationScale;
    gesture.ManipulationUpdated += gesture_ManipulationUpdated;
    gesture.ManipulationStarted += gesture_ManipulationStarted;
    gesture.ManipulationCompleted += gesture_ManipulationCompleted;
```

In my pointer events:

```
 private void PointerPressed_1(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var point = e.GetIntermediatePoints(null);
   gesture.ProcessDownEvent(point[0]);
}

private void PointerMoved_1(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   gesture.ProcessMoveEvents(e.GetIntermediatePoints(null));
}

private void PointerReleased_1(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var point = e.GetIntermediatePoints(null);
    gesture.ProcessUpEvent(point[0]);
    gesture.CompleteGesture();
}

void gesture_ManipulationCompleted(GestureRecognizer sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Manipulation Completed {0}", args.Cumulative.Scale);
    }

void gesture_ManipulationStarted(GestureRecognizer sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Manipulation Started {0}", args.Cumulative.Scale);
    }

void gesture_ManipulationUpdated(GestureRecognizer sender, ManipulationUpdatedEventArgs args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Manipulation Updated {0}", args.Cumulative.Scale);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to urn on all the flags in the gesture settings property. As described in your link:

```
gesture.gestureSettings =
        Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.manipulationRotate |
        Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.manipulationTranslateX |
        Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.manipulationTranslateY |
        Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.manipulationScale |
        Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.manipulationRotateInertia |
        Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.manipulationScaleInertia |
        Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.manipulationTranslateInertia |
        Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.tap;
```